# It is as though~ vs. It appears as though~

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Colloquially, *can* (= ‘possibility’) is very often a proposal for future action: *We can see about that tomorrow.* In fact with second- and third- person subjects, *can* expresses a familiar though tactful imperative – the type of imperative that might be used by the captain of a sports team to the team members, or by the producer of a play to its cast: *Mike and Willy, you can be standing over there; and Janet can enter from behind that curtain.* **It is as though** the speaker does not like to exert authority openly, so, counting on co-operation from Mike and Willy, he/she merely suggests that a certain plan of action is POSSIBLE.

(from <Meaning and the English Verb(3rd ed.)> by Geoffrey Leech p.74)

Here, what's the diffrence between "It is as though the speaker ~ POSSIBLE" and "It appears as though the speaker ~ POSSIBLE"?

Comment: **It is as though...**  in sentences like this has the sense 'it seems to be the case that...", so it is unnecessary to include **appears**.

Comment: Then, how about the examples of the following link? https://ludwig.guru/s/it+appears+as+though

Comment: Both versions are used; I personally consider _appears_ to be somewhat redundant.